# Need Advice to Use Fragment on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments

here i want to develop an app that can run a simple quiz for psychology character test, but here i need some advice on how to show the question on the activity. Because i want to showing each question without moving to other activity.

This is my temporary layout (it's still ugly XD), but i want the question can appear on the inside of that red box. And when user press Next button, the question inside that box can changed but before it change the app has been stored the answer of previous question.

I really don't know how to use fragment or something like that.

NB. This is my mainActivity look :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your app I would recommend **not** to use fragments at all, it will make your app much slower than it can be.

What I would do in your case, is only load the new question in the textbox on pressing next, and call an asynchronous function (`asynctask`) to perform the storage of the answer. This way the user sees no delays whatshowever.

If getting the next question required a server connection, use a progress dialog in between to show the user something happens.

Comment: okkay, thanks for your answer, can you gimme some tutorial or reference for asynchronous function?

Comment: is there i must using Void, Void, Void Parameter on my AsyncTask to save the answer? but when the user has answer all the question, the app will count all the answer and show the result to user.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Bas van Stein, using different fragments will slow down the app. What you could do is separate frequently changing part of your screen (e.g. question with answer options) into a fragment and reload it's data on Next/Answer button click. This will separate the code and make it easier to maintain and change it later.
On the other hand you could do it in the activity itself if you don't want to use fragment.